# yii2 making another query inside a join with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, join, activerecord, yii2

I have a join query that i need to remake with active record.. The problem is that the query is pretty hard and I dont know how to make a join in a join...

The query:

```
$query = Product::find()
            ->select([
                'p.*',
                'pv.Units as SaleUnits',
                'pv.Total as  Pv',
            ])
            ->leftJoin('
            (select 
            cl.campaign_list_status
            p.id,
            p.admin_title,
            ao.article,
            sum(ao.article) as Articles,
            sum(ao.units) as Units,
            TRUNCATE(sum(spo.total_price),2) as Total
            from campaign_list cl
                inner join campaign_article ca on ca.id_campaign_list=cl.id 
                group by ao.article) pv','pv.id=p.id')
            ->all();
```

Is that even possible with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple (only as idea):

```
$query = Product::find()
        ->select([
            'p.*',
            'sum(units) as SaleUnits',
            'sum(article) as  Pv',
        ])
        ->leftJoin('campaign_article','???')
        ->leftJoin('campaign_list','???')
        ->groupBy('article')
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

U can execute the same SQL query in Yii2.

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

        $command = $connection->createCommand("Your complete sql query");
        $rows = $command->queryAll();
```